# Why is the PORT number not getting displayed in output screen?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

I am running server by `nodemon` command where I am trying to display the PORT number in which my server is running using `${}`, but, instead of displaying 3000 in output screen, it is displaying `${PORT}` i.e. `Server running on port ${PORT}` instead of `Server running on port 3000.`

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const PORT = 3000 || process.env.PORT;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server running on port ${PORT}'));
```

Output displayed in output screen after running the above code:-

```
[nodemon] 2.0.6
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server running on port ${PORT}
```

Comment: Use backticks(\`) for string  `console.log(\`Server running on port ${PORT}\`)`

Comment: It's not single quote (') but backtick (key on the left side of 1)

Comment: Very much thanks for your help. It has worked successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using single quotes('), use backtick (`). Backtick key can be found on the left side on number 1.

```
console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT}`
```

or you can copy and paste the above line of code.

Answer (score 2):

In JS, the template strings need Backticks ``` `` ``` and the regular strings need Single `''` or Doble `""` quotes. You can either use string concatenation or template string expressions.

```js
let PORT = 80


console.log('The port is ' + PORT);
console.log(`The port is ${PORT}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

This command will work.

```
const PORT = 8080;

app.listen(PORT, () => {console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)});
```

you might have used - quotes '' instead of backticks `` .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).